# WooCommerce -Need to pass Paypal AppID on standard payment

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am modifying woocommerce paypal standard for adaptive payment. Please let me know how to pass paypal AppID through standard payment html mode.

Thanks

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive Payments doesn't work over HTML like Payments Standard does.  You'll need to use PHP or some other programming language to make calls against the PayPal web service API's.

What specifically are you after that you're moving to Adaptive for?  You may be interested in the [PayPal for WooCommerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/) plugin which includes Express Checkout and is more robust than Payments Standard, but not the same as Adaptive Payments either.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew.

I need to include chained payment on my e-commerce application ( want to take some commission and transfer the remaining amount to client ) 

is it possible to modify express checkout ( from Paypal for Woocommerce ) to Adaptive chained payment ?. Will it work if i modify and pass AppID and receiver email ids in express checkout ?. Please let me know the easiest way to include chained payment on application created using Woocommerce plugin.

Thanks